# OpenLayers WFS source with bbox and filter

Tags: openlayers, wfs, extents, gml

I am trying to work with the French IGN geoportal which provides a WFS source of data.

I have worked out how to use OpenLayers' Vector source with

```typescript
const ignPkUrl = (extent: Extent, projection: string = 'EPSG:3857') => {
  return `https://wxs.ign.fr/topographie/geoportail/wfs?version=2.0.0&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typename=BDTOPO_V3:point_de_repere&outputformat=application/json&srsname=${projection}&bbox=${extent.join(',')},${projection}`;
};
const ignPKWFSSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: e => ignPkUrl(e),
  strategy: bbox,
});
```

but the BBox strategy returns too much features that I don't need.

I tried to figure out how to use the `filter` parameter (which is incompatible with the `bbox` parameter) and came up with the following XML filter:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <And>
    <And>
      <PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" escape="\" singleChar=".">
        <PropertyName>route</PropertyName>
        <Literal>A*</Literal>
      </PropertyIsLike>
      <PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" escape="\" singleChar=".">
        <PropertyName>cote</PropertyName>
        <Literal>D</Literal>
      </PropertyIsLike>
    </And>
    <BBOX xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
      <PropertyName>geometrie</PropertyName>
      <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:3857">
        <gml:coordinates>432026.55,5401138.14,436574.55,5405657.47</gml:coordinates>
      </gml:Box>
    </BBOX>
  </And>
</Filter>
```

what this is supposed to do is get the features that have `A*` in their `route` *and* `D` in their `cote` *and* within the given BBox.

With this, the request is sent without error but no matter where I set my BBox, I get a grand total of 0 features.

Is there any other way to use a filter *and* a Bbox with a WFS source or should I try something different?

> Note: The `PropertyName` is correct despite not being the usual `the_geom`

---

**Edit:**

Taking into account what nmtoken said about the server only working with EPSG:4326, my query is now like the following:
`https://wxs.ign.fr/topographie/geoportail/wfs?version=2.0.0&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typename=BDTOPO_V3:point_de_repere&outputformat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&filter=(...)`

with the filter XML being

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <And>
    <BBOX xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"> 
      <PropertyName>geometrie</PropertyName>
      <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326"> 
        <gml:coordinates>
3.692779541015625,43.542637937898604,4.056701660156251,43.68519110738575
        </gml:coordinates>
      </gml:Box>
    </BBOX>
    <PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="\"> 
      <PropertyName>route</PropertyName>
      <Literal>A*</Literal>
    </PropertyIsLike>
    <PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="\"> 
      <PropertyName>cote</PropertyName>
      <Literal>D</Literal>
    </PropertyIsLike>
  </And>
</Filter>
```

Still no features in sight...

---

**Edit #2:**
Since `gml:Envelope`, `gml:lowerCorner`, `gml:upperCorner` and `gml:boundBy` aren't recognized by the server, I tried to use the following (within the "ogc" root namespace):

```xml
<BBOX xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <PropertyName>geometrie</PropertyName>
  <Literal>3.69 43.54 4.056 43.68</Literal>
</BBOX>
```

and the server stopped screaming at me, which is good.

The bbox still seems to have no effect.

Comment: try changing your escape char to something that isn't `\ ` or use two `\\ `

Comment: The `<PropertyIsLike>` are working as intended, it's the `<BBOX>` that causes problem.

Comment: I am not sure how lenient the IGN server might be, but WFS 2.0 is based on GML 3.x and "Box + Coordinates" belong to GML 2 https://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/OpenGis/gml/3.0.1/?page=box.html. I would still try Envelope with lowerCorner and upperCorner.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for the input.

Comment: Ok, I tried but the server responds with `org.xml.sax.SAXException: Attempted to construct illegal filter - I dont understand the tag: gml:Envelope`... while `gml:Envelope` is listed in the [`GetCapabilites` of the server](https://wxs.ign.fr/topographie/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities)

Comment: The service only reports support of EPSG:4326 so your request using EPSG:3857 may be the cause of your issue

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know but I tried that like 5 minutes ago: still no features. But thanks.

Comment: Try filter like: `<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"><And><And><PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" escapeChar="\" singleChar="."><ValueReference>route</ValueReference><Literal>A*</Literal></PropertyIsLike><PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" escapeChar="\" singleChar="."><ValueReference>cote</ValueReference><Literal>D</Literal></PropertyIsLike></And><BBOX><ValueReference>geometrie</ValueReference><gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"><gml:lowerCorner>50 -1</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>55 51</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></BBOX></And></Filter>`

Comment: The server is still choking (raising SAX exceptions) on `ValueReference` and `Envelope`

Comment: `<ows:ExceptionText>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Attempted to construct illegal filter - I dont understand the tag: ValueReference. HINT: tags are case-sensitive!...`  but `ValueReference` is correct spelling ~ http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/expr.xsd.  Possibly the service/server is not looking at correct schemas for Filter encoding

Comment: I'll try and contact the maintainers of the server 'cause it's driving me crazy.

Comment: For example here's a similar example from OGC ~ https://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/examples/3.2.1/filter04.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work with CQL filter. When using CQL filter, BBOX has to be specified as a part of filter, not as a request parameter. To be on the safe side, I used `EPSG:4326` for WFS request.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
function url(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
  var reprojExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
  var cqlFilter = "cql_filter=route LIKE 'A%' AND cote = 'D'";
  cqlFilter += ' AND BBOX(geometrie,' + reprojExtent.join(',') + ",'EPSG:4326'" + ')';
  cqlFilter = encodeURI(cqlFilter);
  return 'https://wxs.ign.fr/topographie/geoportail/wfs?version=2.0.0&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&' + 
         'typename=BDTOPO_V3:point_de_repere&outputformat=application/json&' + 
         'srsname=EPSG:4326&' + cqlFilter;
}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857', dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'}),
  url: url,
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
```

This is how the result looks like then for a part of the map:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm (and cleaner than wonky XML). Still have to figure out what to do when the bbox is large enough to hit the feature limit, it does not seem to reload features when the bbox changes to a smaller area that already has been processed. But many thanks.